# Непревзойденный - прилагательное, до сих пор непревзойденный?

Tags: орфография, грамматика

1. В чём заключается тайна великих итальянских скрипичных мастеров, создавших непревзойдённые до сих пор шедевры?
2. Именно творчество Паганини без преувеличения можно назвать наивысшей точкой во всей истории академического скрипичного искусства — его главнейшей, до сих пор не превзойдённой кульминацией.

В орфографическом словаре:непревзойдённый; кр. ф. -ён, -ённа, прилагательное. (Хотя, с другой стороны, там же: Орфографический словарь

превзойдённый; кр. ф. -ён, -ена, то есть причастие)

А раз прилагательное, то зависимые слова не влияют на написание с НЕ. Например: •   неприспособленный к тяжелым работам человек (не умеет приспособиться, непрактичный). Следовательно, во втором предложении надо писать слитно: до сих пор непревзойдённой кульминацией?

Answer (score 2):

Непревзойдённый - самый совершенный, прилагательное. Именно в этом смысле употреблено в первом предложении, поэтому с НЕ пишется слитно.

Во втором случае как будто бы то же самое, но оттенок появился, так и слышится слово НИКЕМ, сыграла роль инверсия. Обстоятельство ДО СИХ ПОР, поставленное вперёд, внесло акцент действия, обратило прилагательное вновь в причастие (превзойдённый кем? когда?). Так что раздельное написание здесь можно объяснить авторским смыслом, вложенным в предложение. Но если прочитать без выделения ДО СИХ ПОР, разницы не будет и можно писать слитно, ведь КЕМ? здесь нет,оно домыслено автором.